# how to set reference levels for dummy coding in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say we are using pandas.get_dummies to dummy coding our categorial variable. My question is how to set the reference level for a categorical variable, so that I can specify which level to drop when I use drop_first argument in `get_dummies`? This can be easily done in R, since R has factor datatype. I'm not sure how to do it in pandas. Thanks.

```
dt = pd.Series(list('abcdab'))
pd.get_dummies(dt, drop_first=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create dummy variables using pandas with reference to one value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868967/how-to-create-dummy-variables-using-pandas-with-reference-to-one-value)

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.get_dummies(
  pd.Categorical(
    Predictors_1['cylinders'],
    categories=list(
      reversed(
        list(
          Predictors_1.cylinders.value_counts().index
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  drop_first=True
)
```

Comment: IMO This answer requires some explanation, doesn't it?